# Does VS Express or VS:WebDev Express include XSLT debugging

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, xslt, visual-studio-express, xslt-tools

Can anyone tell me if VS Express (C#, VB, etc) editions contain the XSLT debugger, or the VS Web Developer?

Unfortunately due to burecratic overhead we need something relatively quick that's free and reputable, or alternaviely, if anyone can suggest a product which is licensed perpeptually (i.e. XMLSpy is not).

Answer (score 5):

**This is what** ***[the authoritative official MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255812.aspx)*** **says**:

XSLT Debugging

> Visual Studio supports debugging XSLT
>   style sheets. Using the debugger, you
>   can set break points in an XSLT style
>   sheet, step into an XSLT style sheet
>   from code, and so on.
>
> **Note**
>
> XSLT debugging is available in the
>   Professional and Team Editions.

Comment: @Alejandro: _____________  :)